# NEO4J Slow query for similar recipes

Tags: neo4j

I am new to NEO4J but have been working with MySQL for many years. Now I have created a database with 700 000 user, 800 000 cookbooks and 1,6M saved recipes i NEO4J.

The structure of the nodes are like this (:User)-[:CREATED]-(:Cookbook)-[:SAVED]-(:Recipe). All the users and recipes are unique, but one user can have multipel cookbooks and every cookbook can have multipel recipes.

I'm trying to find similar recipes by looking at witch recipes are in the same cookbook. This is my query:

```
MATCH(r:Recipe {recipe_id:2987431})--()--(similar:Recipe)
USING INDEX r:Recipe(recipe_id)
WITH similar,toFloat(count(similar)) as same
MATCH (similar)-[rel]-()
WITH similar, same, toFloat(count(rel)) as total
WHERE (same/total) > 0.05 AND same > 1
RETURN similar, same, total, (same/total) as percent
ORDER BY same DESC
LIMIT 20
```

I order the result by recipes with most common cookbooks first. I also filter out all the recipes where less than 5% of total cookbooks are the same as the first recipe. They also need to have more than 1 common cookbook.

The problem is that the query takes around 1 second to execute which is way to long for using at our site. I'm currently testing it on an EC2 m3.x2large server a Amazon.

Is there any way to speed up the query or should it be constructed in a totally different way?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas how to speed things up.

- It is generally faster to `MATCH` excplicitly where possible (i.e. define direction and relationship type).
- I think you can `MATCH` everything in one step and do not need to split up matching of similar recipes and all cookbooks for the similar recipes.
- If you `MATCH` from one recipe to similar, you do not need to filter on the `count(similar)` or `same`. The query will return only results where at least one similar is found.
- Last thing is that you `MATCH` one recipe to *all* similar recipes and later use the number of all similar recipes as `same`. If you want to filter for similar recipes by the number of common cookbooks, you need to filter on the cookbook or relationship.

---

```
MATCH (r:Recipe {recipe_id:2987431})-[:SAVED]->(common_cb:Cookbook)<-[:SAVED]-(similar:Recipe)-[similar_total:SAVED]->(:Cookbook)
WITH similar, count(common_cb) as num_common_cb, toFloat(count(similar))/toFloat(count(similar_total)) as percent
WHERE percent > 0.05
RETURN similar, num_common_cb, percent
ORDER BY num_common_cb
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your query and fixed the direction of the relationships and added DESC in the order by. But unfortunately it was even slower. The query took over 5 sec and the results where not the same. 
The most popular similar recipe had 29 common cookbooks, but according to the new query the most popular hade 132,130 common cookbooks. I think the problem is that count(common_cb) will count every row of every recipe-cookbook-recipe-cookbook combination.

Comment: I added DISTINCT in the count()-functions. Then the result is correct, but still slow. MATCH (r:Recipe {recipe_id:2987431})<-[:SAVED]-(common_cb:Cookbook)-[:SAVED]->(similar:Recipe)<-[similar_total:SAVED]-(:Cookbook)
WITH similar, count(distinct common_cb) as num_common_cb, toFloat(count(distinct common_cb))/toFloat(count(distinct similar_total)) as percent
WHERE percent > 0.05
RETURN similar, num_common_cb, percent
ORDER BY num_common_cb DESC

Comment: Have tou profiled the query? What does that say? Which part of the query is taking time?

Comment: Profiling sounds entirely reasonable. I had a similar thing where a single `MATCH` was faster. Depends on the graph though, so maybe not a good answer. But maybe the bullet points help.